Intuitive understanding of the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra of a stopping time $\tau$
I would like to better understand the basic intuition behind the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra of a stopping time $\tau$.

Definition. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathfrak{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t,t\geq 0)$ be the natural filtration on this space. The sigma-algebra at a stopping time $\tau$ is given as:
$$
\mathcal{F}_\tau = \{ A \in \mathcal{F}: A \cap \{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t, \forall t \geq 0 \}
$$

In words, my understanding is, that :
An event $A$ is observable at a stopping time $\tau$, if and only if, it can be determined if $A$ and $\{\tau \leq t\}$ both occurred or not, based on the information $\mathcal{F}_t$ $\forall t \geq 0$. That is, you should be able to tell the value of the random variable $\mathbf{1}_{A}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{\tau \leq t\}}$ given $\mathcal{F}_t$ for any arbitrary time $t \geq 0$.
Is my understanding correct?
I tried to further understand couple of examples in my book.
Let $(B_t,t\geq 0)$ be a standard brownian motion. For concreteness, let $\tau=\inf \{t:B_t > 3\}$ and say, the brownian path first exceeds $3$ at time $1$.
Example 1. The event $\{B_\tau > 0\}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}_\tau$. Our expectation is that we should know the value of the stopped process, given all information upto $\tau$.
Let's apply the definition.
At time $t=0.50$, I know $\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau \leq 0.5\}}=0$ and  $\mathbf{1}_{\{B_\tau > 0\}} = 1$ by definition, so the product $\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau \leq 0.5\}} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{B_\tau > 0\}} = 0$.
At time $t=1.00$, I learn $\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau \leq 0.5\}}=1$ and the value of the stopped process $B_\tau = 3$, so $\mathbf{1}_{\{B_\tau > 0\}}=1$.
$\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau \leq 0.5\}} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{B_\tau > 0\}}$ can be determined for all times $t$.
Thus, $\{B_\tau > 0\} \in \mathcal{F}_\tau$.
Example 2. The event $\{B_1 > 0\}$ is not in $\mathcal{F}_\tau$. Our expectation is that, since $\tau$ is random, in general, given information upto time $\tau$, $\mathcal{F}_\tau$, I don't expect to know if the Brownian motion exceeds $0$ at time $1$.
Let's apply the definition.
Consider $t=0.50$. The value of $\mathbf{1}_{\{B_1 > 0\}}$ cannot be determined given $\mathcal{F}_{0.50}$. So,  $\{B_1 > 0\} \notin \mathcal{F}_\tau$.
Have I applied the definition and argued correctly for examples (1) and (2) correct?
